# Is this possible to replace waterline-orientdb adapter with sails-orientdb adapter?

Tags: sails.js, orientdb, waterline, sails-orientdb

I am trying to replace waterline-orientdb with sails-orientdb adapter but on the top I want to use waterline still, as there are issues with waterline-orientdb adapter regarding edges of orientdb so is this possible to use sails-orientdb adapter under waterline?
I just want to know can i replace waterline-orientdb with sails-orientdb?

Answer (score 0):

Zeeshan, I'm the developer of waterline-orientdb and I'm not aware of the issue with edges you mention. Can you please raise an issue in https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb and give a few more details? I'll gladly look into it.

Regarding your specific question, you should be able to switch to sails-orientdb but your configuration, models and schema may need adjustments.

### Config

sails-orientdb uses:

```
database: {
  name: 'dataBaseName'
},
```

while waterline-orientdb uses:

```
database: 'dataBaseName'
```

### models / schema

#### Associations

waterline-orientdb converts [Many-to-many through associations](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md#many-to-many-through-associations) (see also balderdashy/waterline#705) into edges but regular **Many-to-many** associations will use a join table (waterline default behaviour). This will be changed in the future, but not supported yet.

Currently I'm not 100% sure how sails-orientdb handles associations.

#### id

In waterline-orientdb an id attribute will be automatically created and replaced by @rid. sails-orientdb does not do this so you may need to adjust your models accordingly.

**EDIT:** *regular **Many-to-many** associations will use a join table (waterline default behaviour)* -> This is no longer true, since v0.10.40 waterline-orientdb will use edges for all kinds of many-to-many associations.

**UPDATE:** former sails-orientdb and waterline-orientdb have converged into sails-orientdb. The new adapter is maintained by the developers of the previous adapters.

Comment: Ok well I will raise an issue on the given link but can you share with me a basic model like i want to see what kind of adjustments?

Comment: Both adapters use the models defined by waterline and both adapters have examples in their github pages: [waterline-orientdb](https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb#example-model-definitions) and [sails-orientdb](https://github.com/vjsrinath/sails-orientdb#profile-model-to-be-associated-with-user-model). What differs is how they handle ids and how they translate the models into edges. Waterline-orientdb maps the id to @rid. For more help with sails-orientdb I suggest you contact the developer (@vjsrinath) through github.